# PerformanceCounter always 0

Tags: c#, .net, performancecounter

I try to read windows performance counters "LogicalDisk / Disk Reads/sec" and "Cluster CSV File System / IO Reads/sec". 
I do it so:

```
string category = "Cluster CSV File System";
string counter = "IO Reads/sec";
string instance = "Volume1";
for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
{
    using (PerformanceCounter perfCounter = new PerformanceCounter(category, counter, instance))
    {
        float value = perfCounter.NextValue();
        Console.WriteLine(i + " - {0}({1}): {2}", category, counter, value);
    }
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

But NextValue() always return 0. Although values is not 0 in performance monitor graph.

How can I get correct values for this counters?

Comment: what does perfCounter.RawValue return?

Comment: There seem to be a few gotcha's with getting the value with NextValue (refer to the notes)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.nextvalue(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should definitely read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.nextvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)

> If the calculated value of a counter depends on two counter reads, the first read operation returns 0.0. Resetting the performance counter properties to specify a different counter is equivalent to creating a new performance counter, and the first read operation using the new properties returns 0.0. The recommended delay time between calls to the `NextValue` method is one second, to allow the counter to perform the next incremental read.

Thus:

```
using(...)
{
    perfCounter.NextValue(); // discard 0
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    float value = perfCounter.NextValue();
    Console.WriteLine(i + " - {0}({1}): {2}", category, counter, value);
}
```